# Sidebar nav don't work with angular and materialize css

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, materialize

I'm starting with Angular and I want to use SidebarNav and Dropdown to set up a practical and responsive menu but it's not working.

I installed and configured **angular2-materialize** and **materialize-css** by the CLI.

I created a component named "Navbar" to contain the menu and performed the following process:

app.module.ts

```
import 'materialize-css';
// import * as M from 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize';
import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';

@NgModule({
  // ... ,
  imports: [
    // ... ,
    // M,
    MaterializeModule
  ],
})
```

but he keeps returning this error:

> Uncaught Error: Couldn't find Materialize object on window. It is
>   created by the materialize-css library. Please import materialize-css
>   before importing angular2-materialize.

The solutions I found here in the forum were unfortunately not useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular2-materialize use materialize version '0.100.2'. In your package.json change materialize-css to "^0.100.2".
Then run npm install.

Comment: Hey Brow! It works!!!! Your solution corrected the problem however the navbar is not working. @ClovisIgnacioFerreira

Comment: Can you provide an example in stackblitz like this one?
[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/materialize)

Comment: Course!!!!! The link ===> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rneeus

Comment: You need to install hammer and hammerjs. You can do this by typing this in the dependencies tab.

Comment: And also add the import in the main.ts: import 'hammerjs';

Comment: Thanks again for the tip. It worked!
Now there is the Navbar that doesn't work responsive.